# Typescript 'keyof InstanceType<T>' cannot be used to index type error

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's the sample code:

```
class Base {}

function fn<T extends typeof Base>(
    Cls: T,
    prop: keyof InstanceType<T>,
) {
    return (new Cls())[prop];
}
```

TS Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8C+AodAzArgO2ABcBLAez2izwB4AVaBAD0ITwBMZCBPABwVKxxEAPgAU6aJOgBhEBABc0WgBoJUngCdSPRQGsEXAdACSeCITAEEtXgjrDVAShRrJGhIRwaKovAgDuMnKijo4A2praALoA3OgYQA

`prop` should be a property on `Cls`, yet this code doesn't work?

It works if I change `keyof InstanceType<T>` to `keyof Base`, but I want the function to work with any subclass of `Base`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is doable:

```js
class Base {
  base = 'base'
}

class A extends Base {
  a = 'a'
}
class B extends Base {
  b = 'b'
}

class C {
  c = 'c'
}


const fn = <
  T extends typeof Base,
  Instance extends InstanceType<T>
>(Cls: new () => Instance, prop: keyof Instance,
) => new Cls()[prop];

const result = fn(A, 'base') // ok

const result2 = fn(B, 'b') // ok

const result3 = fn(Base, 'base') // ok

const result4 = fn(A, 'b') // expected error

const result5 = fn(B, 'a') // expected error

const result6 = fn(C, 'x') // expected error
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that TypeScript compiler reacts badly when `InstanceType` is used on generics.

It works if you change the generic parameter to the instance type, which should be equivalent to original code:

```js
function fn<T extends Base>(
    Cls: new () => T, 
    prop: keyof T
) {
    return new Cls()[prop];
}
```

Comment: This works in my example, but in my actual code, I still need the class's type.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of problems here:

```ts
class Base {}

function fn<T extends typeof Base>(
    Cls: T, // <--- Cls is already an instance of T
    prop: InstanceType<T>, // <-- if you want properties of the class use keyof T
) {
    return (new Cls())[prop]; // <-- You cannot call new on instance
}
```

With these in mind, this may work for you:

```ts
class Base {}

function fn<T extends Base>(
    Cls: T,
    prop: keyof T,
) {
    return Cls[prop];
}
```

TS Playground: https://tsplay.dev/WJ9DDm

However, if you are passing the class to `fn` and not the instance, the answer by Wang Weixuan fits better.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to `new Cls` And `InstanceType` Try this one:

```
class Base {}

function fn<T extends typeof Base>(Cls: T,prop: keyof T) {
     return Cls[prop];
}
```