# How can I create generic function that only accepts instances of a type with a specific nested type?

Tags: typescript

**UPDATE**

I made a walkaround myself, by move nested type from static field to instane field, which seems to work but was imperfect: https://tsplay.dev/w26Xjw

---

**UPDATE**

The main purposes are:

1. I want create a generice function<T,U> which accept two arguments;
2. The types of these arguments could be `connected/related`
3. While I pass the first argument to the with type of T it should auto infer the type U of the second argument

So the questions would be:

1. How to properly make these two types connected/related? I tried to use nested type, as my previous post below, which may not be a suitable way but I don't how. Any advises are welcome.
2. Once these types are connected/related, if possible, could the later one be auto infered from the first one?

So that when the user passes the first argument the generic function should restrict the type of the second argument.

Something similar in C++ I'd like to write:

```
class A {
    class InnerType {}
}

template<typename T>
void test(const T& first, const typename T::InnerType& second);
```

---

I want to created a generic function which accepts two args:

1. The first arg should be a type of `T` and there would be a nested type `T.Param`
2. The second arg should be a type of `T.Param`

```
class A {
    static Param = class {
        ....
    }
}

class B {
    static Param = class {
        ....
    }
}

// How can I make the T/P match the requirements explain above?
function test<T, P>(first:T, second:P) {
}
```

And then such invoking should pass:

```
test(new A(), new A.Param()); // OK
test(new A(), new B.Param()); // Fail
test(new B(), new A.Param()); // Fail
test(new B(), new B.Param()); // OK
```

Comment: Please provide more detail.  As you can see, both people who have attempted to answer your question still don't understand what you want. Per StackExchange rules, you are supposed to supply a *complete* example showing exactly what you are trying to do. e.g. above you need to show what `test` does with the arguments. As I've already stated below and in your dupe question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68032159/how-can-i-create-a-generic-function-that-only-accepts-instances-of-classes-with/68085592#68085592), what you ask as shown is impossible.

Comment: @Inigo The post was updated. Hope it make you clear this time.

Comment: Ok, this helps a lot, because you just admitted using "nested types" isn't important, it was just something you are trying. The important thing is to explain your underlying problem, not ask us to fix your solution which may be wrong in the first place.

Comment: @jayatubi I added my own answer, lets continue chat there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67979663/typescript-keyof-instancetypet-cannot-be-used-to-index-type-error/68118171#68118171) answer might be interesting for you.

What about next solution?

```js
class ParamA {
    foo: number = 0
}

class ParamB {
    bar: string = ''
}

class A {
    InnerType = () => ParamA
}

class B {
    InnerType = () => ParamB
}


function test1<
    T extends { InnerType: any },
    P extends InstanceType<ReturnType<T["InnerType"]>>,
    >(first: T, second: P) {
    // ...
}

test1(new A(), new ParamA());
test1(new B(), new ParamA()); // error
test1(new A(), new ParamB()); //error
test1(new B(), new ParamB());
```

Comment: The `FakeFunc` could be omitted and then this answer matches what I need. Thanks :p

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple of different ways to do it, depending in part on which argument you want to drive the process. You can drive it with the first argument:

```typescript
function test1<T extends {Param: unknown}, P extends T["Param"]>(first: T, second: P) {
    // ...
}
```

or the second:

```typescript
function test2<P, T extends {Param: P}>(first: T, second: P) {
    // ...
}
```

With those, you get these results:

```typescript
test1(A, A.Param); // works
test1(B, A.Param); // error on second argument

test2(A, A.Param); // works
test2(B, A.Param); // error on first argument
```

[Playground with both](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=1&pln=32&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQgFzBglsaACmAE5gC20AvNKJDMmo9GQKYYAWA9gCYAUAlIhRMRAelHQAdNOEiAvrKbip0yYoUKktKNABCQxpmx5CJclRrgdDEdG44AZg5bEWAOwwBZNlz6CbtmjKqoqMCoHBIWFImg4Arm7AuJxu0BgsmACMADwAKtAsAB7pbtz0RKRkAFzQCQDWbpwA7m5yADSEBcXuZdC5ANoARBXkgwC6AHy8DjjEmDW5HRAswCncNQT+ipFqsQlJOClpGRgATNkEHflFJb0II9WEclMzcxgLSytrG1uMOzFIJDpLK8WAdWCSB78ADc0GUTU4xDqECBJ0yvF04MhZjIMLhEhcxER0COy1WpWgJAA5nFWB5AcCzqCsVDYfDEcjUZhThiWTi8cpCcSjq9MJTiDS6RgkEA)

---

Note that because TypeScript's type system is *structural* (based on the shapes of types) rather than nominal (based on the names of types), in the playground link I added things to `A.Param` and `B.Param` so they wouldn't have the same shape. Otherwise, since their shapes are the same (empty classes), either can be used in place of the other.

Comment: It looks pretty perfect. Can I make this work not only with the class itself but also the instances of the classes? Such as test1(new A(), new A.Param());

Comment: @jayatubi - I'm sure you can, but sadly I don't know how. I'm not strong on constructor types I'm afraid. I tried with [`InstanceType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype), but no luck. Would you like me to delete the answer so people don't get the impression the question is answered?

Comment: (I suggest editing the question with calls that you want to work and others that you want to fail.)

Comment: Even though this answer doesn't meet my requirements but it is very enlightening. I'd like to keep it.

Comment: @jayatubi regarding your first comment, take a look at my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67979663/typescript-keyof-instancetypet-cannot-be-used-to-index-type-error/68118171#68118171

Comment: The problem is that it is impossible to infer constructor type from the instance, especially static properties.

Comment: @captain-yossarian. As you mentioned the constructor couldn't be inferred so I tried to move this type relationship from static to instance field. I made a walkaround but it's inperfect: https://tsplay.dev/w26Xjw

Comment: @jayatubi look like it works. Why it does not perfect?

Comment: @captain-yossarian. I added a `FakeFunc` to infer the type but it couldn't prevent unexpected behaviour if user invokes it by mistake.

Comment: What about returning class instead of function ?https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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

Comment: @jayatubi - Folks, could you take this discussion to a chat room please? So I'm not constantly getting pinged? Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In complement to this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68031094/3388225).

To make your functions accept only *instances* of those types you may define them as:

```ts
function test1<
    T extends {Param: { new (): unknown }}, 
    P extends T["Param"]
>(first: T, second: InstanceType<P>) {}

function test2<
    P, 
    T extends {Param: { new (): P }}
>(first: T, second: P) {}

test1(A, new A.Param()); // works
test1(B, new A.Param()); // error on second argument

test2(A, new A.Param()); // works
test2(B, new A.Param()); // error on first argument
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WP5okw)

Comment: I'd like both the arguments are instances instead of types aka the first argument should be `new A()` instead of `A`

Answer (score 0):

### You can't.

Though I do have a workaround for you.

> Note: I'm copying my answer to [your duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68032159/how-can-i-create-a-generic-function-that-only-accepts-instances-of-classes-with/68085592#68085592) because it took me a lot of time to put it together. The example I give below was based on that question, so isn't *exactly* the same as above, but  it's close and it covers the issue completely.

Typescript does not include static members as part of the type that a class represents. [The following is in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-mRqIsAH5oPhCwBNUi0aJgaiDOTXaAASTkgxg1Cx0BATDmYBA0AZKwgwAQviUcgoI4qF-iK-h-jGyFIx189dSwGna+2YCUKkQeKWXYJFE0TuUROAeTg8yqEkyQpXwqTVOQXEZZk2Q5LlsC8HsAgFWNQnUAVEyFUVxT3KU9xlUN5UVaIVTwIA) so you can see the error messages. I add `ParamClass` because we need *some* way to refer to the type of `Param` in the generic function.

```js
class ParamClass {
    foo: number = 0
}

class A1 {
    Param: typeof ParamClass = class {
        foo: number = 0
    }
}

class A2 {
    static Param: typeof ParamClass = class {
        foo: number = 0
    }
}

const a1: A1 = {}  //fails type check: Property 'Param' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'A1'.(2741)

const a2: A2 = {}  //passes type check, static class member is not part of type A2


function test1<T extends {Param: typeof ParamClass}>(c: T): T {
  return c
}

test1(new A1())  //passes

test1(new A2())  //fails: Property 'Param' is missing in type 'A2' but required in type '{ Param: typeof ParamClass; }'.(2345)


// But what if we define T to have a static member? 
// You can't. It's not legal Typescript:
//
//      'static' modifier cannot appear on a type member.(1070)
//
function test2<T extends {static Param: typeof ParamClass}>(c: T): T {
  return c
}
```

### my workaround

[in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcwFsDC4rQN4FgBQ0h0AZgPakBc0AdgK7IBGApgtALzQAM+AvvvqEgwAggGZs+ItAgAXMDICWwOIhRUZATwAOTUsRVI0GGB0GZcBKUTKUa9Zqw7dLhPi+gBzJjIMoAFACU2NCSVoQI3rQI1NBiAHTwhqGuIXhuAsbQAEISafx4+MS01MCKpDEyTLIAjAA8ACrQTAAeldQAJjBYiWrQmjp6vkZCPAB8fsBU9QFTuYTA5bLQWqrI7NDACauhAPQ7NKQA7tAapLQbYDHtpNCHABbyTABuLCdnt5c+hwoydxuZPWQABomnEPHFUvNFj4VoYAJLUWSXYBMdbUJjHWH+IKhCIyKIxYC8fKVGp+dHHMSBILQPbLIRVPraVHAO5MYAAaxJVRk1XJGOy1MIdOIYAUIBg-RZbM5QA)

```js
class ParamClass {
    foo: number = 0
}

class A3 {
    static Param: typeof ParamClass = class {
        foo: number = 0
    }
    get Param() { 
        return A3.Param
    } 
}

class B {
}


function test1<T extends {Param: typeof ParamClass}>(c: T): T {
  const param = c.Param
  // now you can do whatever you want with class Param, e.g. 
  const paramInstance = new param() 
  return c
}

test1(new A3())  // passes type check

test1(new B())  // fails type check
```

Comment: Thanks for the explain. What I want is to limit the `argument` which would be passed to the function not create a new one inside the function. In other words I want to make the test function works in this pattern `test(new A3(), new A3.Param())`. I'd like to prepare the argument before invoking. The goal is: when the user passed the first argument, then the second argument should be restricted by the first one.