# How can I create a generic function that only accepts instances of classes with a particular static member?

Tags: typescript

I want to create a generic function which only accepts arguments if their type has a specific static member:

```
class A {
    static Param = class {
        foo: number
    }
}

class B {
}

// How do I require T to have a static Param member?
function test<T>(first: T) {

}

test(new A());    // this should pass type check
test(new B());    // this should fail
```

Comment: The `Param` parameter must be `static`?

Comment: The `static` since the `Param` is an inner class

Comment: You can use base class that has foo parameter and  `class A extend Base` and then in you function `T extends Base`. But the requirement is that `Param` mustn't be static.
See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDeBYAUNT0AKYBOYAttALzSiQyoZa0BmA9gwFzQB2AroQEYJ6nQAjAAZ0tAL7pJadBSjQAgtAQAPAC4I2AExjwICaNVpT0s8PNiGTMtAHpb0ABIMA7uTBtoASWiEwAawM1AAsDABVoNQZoAAdKaABLOkjQ8gY2CDU8DmAo-gZkiODIaDAcfCJoOgSEEC10Og42XIT0yIRMgB4I1Q1tXUQAPgAKarxM1jCASisbaXQNTOG2BDcFYampgG5ae2gAeQBpBY61ZdW4De3dhwAxMASQIA)

Comment: I know this approach and I'll call it as `check the type of the value, or instance`. However, what I want to do here is to `check the type of the value's constructor`.

Comment: I updated your question to reflect your comments. If I got it wrong, then you need to make it very clear what you want, with a complete example that shows what you are trying to achieve, e.g. your sample `test` function should show why it needs `Param` to exist as a static member.

Comment: Please clarify your comment about "type of the value's constructor". Do you mean `typeof A`?  Remember, in JS and TS, "value's constructor" is synonymous with "value's class".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can't.

Though I do have a workaround for you.

Typescript does not include static members as part of the type that a class represents. [The following is in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-mRqIsAH5oPhCwBNUi0aJgaiDOTXaAASTkgxg1Cx0BATDmYBA0AZKwgwAQviUcgoI4qF-iK-h-jGyFIx189dSwGna+2YCUKkQeKWXYJFE0TuUROAeTg8yqEkyQpXwqTVOQXEZZk2Q5LlsC8HsAgFWNQnUAVEyFUVxT3KU9xlUN5UVaIVTwIA) so you can see the error messages. I add `ParamClass` because we need *some* way to refer to the type of `Param` in the generic function.

```js
class ParamClass {
    foo: number = 0
}

class A1 {
    Param: typeof ParamClass = class {
        foo: number = 0
    }
}

class A2 {
    static Param: typeof ParamClass = class {
        foo: number = 0
    }
}

const a1: A1 = {}  //fails type check: Property 'Param' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'A1'.(2741)

const a2: A2 = {}  //passes type check, static class member is not part of type A2


function test1<T extends {Param: typeof ParamClass}>(c: T): T {
  return c
}

test1(new A1())  //passes

test1(new A2())  //fails: Property 'Param' is missing in type 'A2' but required in type '{ Param: typeof ParamClass; }'.(2345)


// But what if we define T to have a static member? 
// You can't. It's not legal Typescript:
//
//      'static' modifier cannot appear on a type member.(1070)
//
function test2<T extends {static Param: typeof ParamClass}>(c: T): T {
  return c
}
```

### my workaround

[in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYCcwFsDC4rQN4FgBQ0h0AZgPakBc0AdgK7IBGApgtALzQAM+AvvvqEgwAggGZs+ItAgAXMDICWwOIhRUZATwAOTUsRVI0GGB0GZcBKUTKUa9Zqw7dLhPi+gBzJjIMoAFACU2NCSVoQI3rQI1NBiAHTwhqGuIXhuAsbQAEISafx4+MS01MCKpDEyTLIAjAA8ACrQTAAeldQAJjBYiWrQmjp6vkZCPAB8fsBU9QFTuYTA5bLQWqrI7NDACauhAPQ7NKQA7tAapLQbYDHtpNCHABbyTABuLCdnt5c+hwoydxuZPWQABomnEPHFUvNFj4VoYAJLUWSXYBMdbUJjHWH+IKhCIyKIxYC8fKVGp+dHHMSBILQPbLIRVPraVHAO5MYAAaxJVRk1XJGOy1MIdOIYAUIBg-RZbM5QA)

```js
class ParamClass {
    foo: number = 0
}

class A3 {
    static Param: typeof ParamClass = class {
        foo: number = 0
    }
    get Param() { 
        return A3.Param
    } 
}

class B {
}


function test1<T extends {Param: typeof ParamClass}>(c: T): T {
  const param = c.Param
  // now you can do whatever you want with class Param, e.g. 
  const paramInstance = new param() 
  return c
}

test1(new A3())  // passes type check

test1(new B())  // fails type check
```