# Generic typing for factory function

Tags: typescript

I am currently trying to write a factory function that accepts a class, and some constructor arguments and have it be typesafe all the way through.

I started with something like this

```
class A {
  constructor(public a: number) {}
}

class B {
  constructor(public b: string) {}
}

class C {
  constructor(public c: boolean) {}
}

function abcInitializer<T extends typeof A | typeof B | typeof C>(
  Clazz: T,
  args: ConstructorParameters<T>[0],
): InstanceType<T> {
  return new Clazz(args);
}

const result = abcInitializer(A, 12);
```

The typing to the caller is mostly correct (when I pass in A, the typing of result is A). But this implementation has a couple issues. The first is `args` does not seem to be associated with `Clazz` so when passing it to the constructor, typescript gives the error

```
Type 'A | B | C' is not assignable to type 'InstanceType<T>'.
  Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'InstanceType<T>'.ts(2322)
```

And related, if I cast/ignore that issue, then the following error will be

```
Argument of type 'ConstructorParameters<T>[0]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

and finally within the function if I do something like

```
const result: T = new Clazz(args);
```

I also get the error

```
Type 'A | B | C' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'A | B | C'.
    Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'A'.ts(2322)
```

Is there a way to get this working? I know one way would be to have multiple declarations of the function `abcInitializer` but I am trying to see is there a way to handle this correctly with generics.

Thanks!

Comment: RElated questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67979663/typescript-keyof-instancetypet-cannot-be-used-to-index-type-error#answer-68118171 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68030997/how-can-i-create-generic-function-that-only-accepts-instances-of-a-type-with-a-s/68159603#68159603 , https://catchts.com/oop-style#handle_keyof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For TypeScript to understand that you actually want your `abcInitializer` function to only receive classes, you also have to put this restriction into the function type like so:

```
function abcInitializer<
  T extends (new (...args: any) => any) & (typeof A | typeof B | typeof C)
>(Clazz: T, ...args: ConstructorParameters<T>): InstanceType<T> {
  return new Clazz(...args);
}
```

I also changed it so that it will receive any number of constructor parameters instead of just one, since the compiler also checks that all constructor parameters are matching.

Here is the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-sid-f9nv2?file=/src/index.ts) I used to verify that it works.

Comment: Yup good call on the constructor function - thanks!